# Manipulating the elements of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists of the form:

```
list1 = {{1, 2.003}, {3, 2.01}, {2, 1.0011}};
list2 = {{2, 1.001}, {3, 2.0034}, {2, 1.0001}};
```

I want to do the following:

Get the absolute value of subtracting each two second sub-elements in the two lists from each other. For example `{1, 2.003}` from `list1` and `{3, 2.0034}` from `list2`. $|2.003-2.0034|$ and if it is in the range from 0.0001 to 0.001 subtract their corresponding first items i.e. $|1-3|$ in absolute value also.

How to do that for all the elements in the two lists in Mathematica?

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that you want something like the following:

To do something to each pair of elements from `list1` and `list2` you can use [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html):

```
table = Outer[Module[{d = Abs @ Subtract @ ##}, 
    If[0.0001 <= d[[2]] <= 0.001, d, d[[2]]]] &, list1, list2,  1];
```

Add `list1` and `list2` as row and column headers and display using [`Grid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html):

```
Grid[Prepend[Join[List /@ list1, table, 2], Prepend[list2, ""]],
  Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
  Dividers -> {{1 -> Black, -1 -> Black, 2 -> Gray}, {1 -> Black, -1 -> Black, 2 -> Gray}}]
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I want , thank you very much. Appreciate the Help.

Comment: @Rami1234, glad it worked for you. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: Can you help to only get those who satisfy the condition as the table is very big, it has about 700 rows.

Comment: @Rami1234, try `table2 = Outer[Module[{d = Abs @ Subtract @ ##}, 
    If[0.0001 <= d[[2]] <= 0.001, d, Nothing]] &, list1, list2,  1];`

Comment: it gave this 
\begin{array}{|c|ccc}
\hline
 \text{} & \{3,2.0034\} & \{2,1.001\} & \{2,1.0001\} \\
\hline
 \{1,2.003\} & \{2,0.0004\} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \{3,2.01\} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \{2,1.0011\} & \{0,0.0001\} & \text{} & \text{} \\
\end{array}

Comment: Change last @kglr's suggestion to `table2 = Outer[Module[{d = Abs @ Subtract @ ##}, If[0.0001 <= d[[2]] <= 0.001, d, ""]] &, list1, list2, 1];`. This gives empty string when `If` condition is false, and empty cell in further `Grid`.